# Universal approximation bounds of the form $\|f(x)-\hat{f}(x;w)\|\leq \varepsilon \|f(x)\|$

Tags: approximation, neural-networks

It is known that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is an appropriate neural network architecture, such that one can approximate any continuous function $f:[0,1]^n\to[0,1]^m$ by the neural network output $\hat{f}(\bullet;w):[0,1]^n\to[0,1]^m$ as:
$$
\|f(x)-\hat{f}(x;w)\|\leq \varepsilon, \forall x\in[0,1]^n \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (1)
$$
**My question is** if its possible to derive a similar result, but with a conclusion of the following form: that for every $\varepsilon'>0$ there exists a suitable architecture such that the estimation $\hat{f}(x;w)$ (different from the one in (1)) complies
$$
\|f(x)-\hat{f}(x;w)\|\leq \varepsilon' \|f(x)\|, \forall x\in[0,1]^n\ \  \quad \quad(2)
$$
This is, the approximation $\hat{f}(x;w)$ gets better if the true output $f(x)$ is small.

I am not trying to show that (1) implies (2), but that there is $\hat{f}$ complying (2) by itself. This is a stronger result, since (2) can imply (1) for appropriate $\varepsilon,\varepsilon'$.

I'm not looking for complete proofs, but just some discussion and suggestions:

-Do you think a result of this form should be able to be proved?

-If (2) is too strong to be proved, what other condition could be feasible to prove, which correctly synthetize the statement "the approximation $\hat{f}(x;w)$ gets better if the true output $f(x)$ is small."?

-Do you have any suggestion on what to look for in order to proceed in the proof?

And one more. Do you think this question fits here, or should be posted at stats.stackexchange.com or math.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I suggest trying to follow along with the proof for the standard universal approximation theorem to see if you can adjust it to your case.  The overview here might be helpful if you want a gentle non-rigorous intuition: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap4.html.  I suggest you first try to prove it for functions of a single variable, i.e., $n=m=1$.  You might start by trying to prove it for a piecewise linear function with only two pieces, then a piecewise linear function with $k$ pieces, then see if you can go from there to an arbitrary continuous function.

Comment: I'll try to follow your advice. Actually, starting with $n=m=1$ and piecewise linear might be a good idea, I was stucked with the general case. Thanks.

Comment: If $m = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ then also $\hat{f}(x) = 0$. This could be problematic if your function has many zeroes, for example $f(x) = x \sin (1/x)$.

Comment: Interesting. I agree. Maybe we should restrict $f$ to have a finite number of zeros for this to be feasible.